# Once-normal package updates are being labeled System Upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, reboot, discover-software-center

For a week or so now, I've had a "System Upgrade" show up in my Kubuntu (22.04.3 LTS) laptop's Discover at least once a day that, when installed, requested I reboot my system. I was confused as to why I was getting them all of a sudden, but since I was unfamiliar with the packages listed, I thought it was just a large influx of security updates.

Now, however, Google Chrome is being labeled under the "security update" section[image: updates] As has been occurring, when I go to install the update, I am *not* prompted for my password (as I should be), and I'm prompted to reboot my computer after the update's been installed.[image: updates-2] This has never occurred before and seems like a great way to introduce malware into my system. How could this have begun? And, more importantly, how do I get back to the way it was? I want to avoid having to reinstall my system all over again - if that's the only option, I may just decide to switch back to Windows.

**Edit**: I'm seeing a bit too late now that I did not expand the "system upgrade" section before screenshotting. Since I've already updated, I'm not sure I can retrieve this. However, the only thing listed was Google Chrome, and the format was identical to what normally appeared when Chrome would be updated as a normal package.

**Edit 2**: It's been a while, but I've collected some new data: first, to the user who said that I "shouldn't be prompted for my password when updating," I have absolutely no clue what this is based on. Using apt/nala, it requires sudo to upgrade packages. On a fresh install of Mint on an old computer, using their software manager prompted for a password to update packages. Doing *anything* to change non-Flatpaks/Snaps/AppImages has always, and continues to, prompt for an admin password. And on that apt/nala note, using either of these tools in the command line does *not* require a reboot, interestingly enough! So, only specifically when using Discover, I am *not* prompted for my password (yes, as I *should* be, based on every other time I've used any Linux distro), and I am requested to reboot my system. I'd say that this is a Discover issue, but it "not needing" my password for something every other part of my system *does* need a password for feels like it might be something deeper, and potentially insecure (*something* in my system is allowing normally password-protected software changes to occur *without* that password - this is obviously a security flaw somewhere). As a final note, I'm also noticing that, when using apt/nala, two packages are being labeled as "held back," with nala telling me it was unable to discern why: `python3-update-manager` and `update-manager-core`. Definitely interesting!

Comment: This change may be related to the switching of more and more components of Ubuntu into snap packages, which can be updated without prompting for passwords. However I would question your logic of switching back to Windows in response to something like this as Windows tends to have even more of a problem with malware than Ubuntu. Yes, you have a valid concern here but it is more theoretical. If you are concerned with security and stability you might want to look into other Linux distributions; Ubuntu semes to have been slipping and the move to snap is one part of why.

Comment: "*I am not prompted for my password (as I should be)*" No, you shouldn't be. Nothing new is being installed nor removed. Package upgrades have not required passwords for many years.

Comment: "*This has never occurred before, and seems like a great way to introduce malware into my system.*" Let's avoid jumping to conclusions. Perhaps try a bit of basic troubleshooting first. For example, does the daily-reboot-requirement show in your logs? Does it still occur if you use apt instead of Discover? And please edit your question to tell us which release of Kubuntu you are running. The version matters.

Comment: @user535733 "No, you shouldn't be..." this is weird, as I've always been prompted for package upgrades ever since I installed Kubuntu on my system. Anything that isn't a flatpak always requests I input my password. Maybe it's a KDE Discover thing? But even then, I feel like I've needed `sudo` when using apt/nala.

"Perhaps try a bit of basic troubleshooting first." Which logfile should I check? As for using apt, I'll need to wait until another update is available, but I'll respond with results when that happens. Finally, I've updated my original post to include the version. Thank you!

Comment: @user535733 I've updated my original post with some new info! The TL;DR is: updating with apt/nala *did* prompt for a password (sudo required), and did *not* require a reboot. I assumed this must be a Discover thing, but I don't know how a front-end software management center managed to bypass the sudo request, unless I've somehow enabled sudo on Discover by default?